# No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am creating a portfolio that consists of investing 100 000 USD every time I generate my purchase signals. This is my code:

```
initial_capital= float(100000.0)
positions = pd.DataFrame(index=signals.index).fillna(0.0)
No_acciones = (initial_capital / GFG['Close']).astype(int)
positions['GFG'] = No_acciones*signals['signal']   
portfolio = positions.multiply(GFG['Close'], axis=0)
portfolio['holdings'] =(positions.multiply(GFG['Close'],axis=0)).sum(axis=1)
portfolio['cash'] = initial_capital - (positions['GFG'].multiply(GFG['Close'], axis=0)).sum(axis=1).cumsum()   
portfolio['total'] = portfolio['cash'] + portfolio['holdings']
portfolio['returns'] = portfolio['total'].pct_change()
print(portfolio.head())
```

I get this error and I do not understand why:

> File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 357, in _get_axis_number
>       .format(axis, type(self)))
>
> ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type

Comment: A series has only 1 dimension, and so `axis=1` doesn't exist. There's only axis 0. One of your `.sum`s is likely being done on a Series rather than a DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks so mouch !... let me see